# adding to an empty list

Tags: java, collections

When I execute the below code it works without any problem.

```
List<String> singletonList = Collections.singletonList("Hello");
List<String> s = Collections.emptyList();
singletonList.addAll(s);
```

However, when I try to do following it gives me compile error. Why?

```
List<String> singletonList = Collections.singletonList("Hello");
singletonList.addAll(List<String> Collections.emptyList());
```

Collections.emptyList is a type-safe way of creating an empty list. But why doesn't my program compile then? I know I cannot add to immutable list (`UnsupportedOperationException`) but adding an empty list is allowed. Actually I was testing this and I noticed above thing.

Comment: after reading the answers, i'm curious to know what java version you are using.

Comment: When you get a compile error and you ask a question about it, always include the exact error message in your question - that makes it a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Collections.emptyList()` returns `List<Object>` which isn't (does not have any type relationship with) `List<String>` so casting is not allowed.

What you need is following:

```
singletonList.addAll(Collections.<String>emptyList());
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code works. But why casting is not allowed? I can write Object o = "abc";

Comment: @ParagJ A `String` is an `Object`, but a `List<String>` is not a `List<Object`>

Comment: There has to be a type relationship (parent-child, child-parent) for the casting to work. e.g. `String` is an `Object`.

Comment: And why this works then ? List<String> s = Collections.emptyList();

Comment: That's when @SotiriosDelimanolis' answer comes into picture. There is some thing called automatic type inference, where compiler tries to infer the return type based on the context. In version 7 it works in the declaration, but as you can see in his answer, in version 8, in works in method call also.

Comment: Ah, ok. Automatic Type Inference! But it's surprising why no-one couldn't notice this in JDK7. Because using Collections.EMPTY_LIST still works in method call in version 7.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8, the type inference is improved. You can do

```
List<String> singletonList = Collections.singletonList("Hello");
singletonList.addAll(Collections.emptyList());
```

The type argument for the invocation of `emptyList()`  will be inferred from the context it is used in, ie. it expects a `Collection<? extends String>`.